# Stored procedures with multiple result sets using Entityframe 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure that returns 2 result sets but the Function Import and the Complex Types only shows the results of the first result set.

I have done some research on this but I haven't found a solution that I am comfortable implementing.

I would appreciate any advice on how to deal with this , I'm sure quite a few of you have had to deal with a similar problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx ?